# how to sort two dimentional array in descending array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have the following array and i want to sort this array in descending order on the base of the "count" index value in php. i have used the following code but it is not working for me. please give me hint to sort array in descending order.

***Array:-***

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => this is text [count] => 0 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [text] => this is second text [count] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [text] => this is third text [count] => 1 )
      )
```

I have tried the following code.

```
function sort_count($a, $b) {
    return $a['count'] - $b['count'];
}
$sorted_array = usort($array, 'sort_count');
```

Comment: It's already has a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Note: Checking your equality acts as an added advantage.

```
function sort_count($a, $b) {
   if ($a['count'] === $b['count']) {
      return 0;
   } else {
       return ($a['count'] > $b['count'] ? 1:-1);
   }
}
$sorted_array = usort($array, 'sort_count');

echo "<pre>";

print_r($array);

echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ascending..

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['count'] - $b['count'];
});
```

Descending..

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) {
   return $b['count'] - $a['count'];
});
```

[Example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82a956a1f33395cbf7fbb6a767f8f08d8ce522b5)

Comment: This will work on PHP 5.3 or higher. (anon functions)  If you are on a lower version.  You need to define the function first.  As you did in your example.

Comment: it doesn't sort in descending order

Answer (score 0):

you can use core php functions like

```
rsort ($array)
arsort($array)
```

also you should read this in php manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
$a1 = array (array ( "text" => "this is text", "count" => 0 ), 
    array ( "text" => "this is text", "count" => 1 ),
    array ( "text" => "this is text", "count" => 2 ),
  );
usort($a1 ,sortArray('count')); 
function sortArray($keyName) {
  return function ($a, $b) use ($keyName) {return ($a[$keyName]< $b[$keyName]) ? 1 : 0;
    };
}
print_r($a1);
```